# Bootsrap Typeahead 3 ajax not working

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to make typeahead input with ajax but it's not working. I tried everything what I find on web but I just stuck.

This is initialization of typeahead:

```js
$('input[name=type_input]').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
      
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/data.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data) {
     return (data);
     }
   });
 }
   });

// this is ajax return {["Data 1","Data 2","Data 3r"]}
```

Comment: Find out where was problem. There must be return process(data) and there was wrong json formating...